# Retrieve field values in a compute of a relationship field odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to retrieve all the values ​​of the records of a model in a `Many2one` field. I don't know if it's possible with a compute.

My class of I want to recover the value:

```
class ResPartner_school(models.Model):

    _name = 'ecole.partner.school'
    _order = 'id desc'

    school_name = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="ecole.establishment.webservice",
                              string="Etablissement Scolaire",
                               default=1)
    school_level = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="ecole.establishment.webservice",
                               string="Niveau Scolaire",
                               compute="_get_level")
```

My other class:

```
class SchoolEstablishmentWebServices(models.Model):

    _name = 'ecole.establishment.webservice'
    _rec_name = "establishment_name"

    establishment_name = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="horanet.school.establishment", string="Etablissement Scolaire")
    id_establishment = fields.Char(string='idEtablissement')
    grade_name = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="horanet.school.grade", string="Niveau Scolaire")
    id_class = fields.Char(string='idClasse')
```

My function in my class `ResPartner_school`:

```
    @api.multi
    def _get_level(self):
        school_level = self.school_name.grade_name

        return school_level
```

How to retrieve all values ​​from the `grade_name` field of the class `SchoolEstablishmentWebServices`?

Comment: What do you mean by "all values"? What do you want to do with the values?

Comment: I want to get all the values ​​in a selection field proposed by Odoo as for a many2One. That's why my function (compute) is located in a many2One relationship field. This field will be in a form generated with a form view in order to save a new record in the model : ecole.partner.school
Thanks

Comment: You can simply use a Many2one field and override `name_get()` of the model of that relation. I will write an answer to such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to show "all" data (depends on how much of data there is) is overriding the `name_get()` of a model with two variants.

1. Variant context-based `name_get()`

First override the `name_get()` of model `ecole.establishment.webservice`

```py
class SchoolEstablishmentWebServices(models.Model):

    _name = 'ecole.establishment.webservice'

    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        res = []
        for webservice in self:
            if 'full_name' in self.env.context:
                res.append((webservice.id, webservice.get_full_name()))
            else:
                res.append((webservice.id, webservice.establishment_name))
        return res

    def get_full_name(self):
        #  example logic
        self.ensure_one()
        full_format = "{establishment}, {grade}"
        return full_format.format(
            establishment=self.establishment_name, grade=self.grade_name)
```

Then you need to put the value `full_name` into the context. You could add it to the field itself, which won't work that good. Better you put that value into the context of the action of the menu, which is used to show your `'ecole.partner.school'` entries.

```xml
    <record id="my.list.action.for.school" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">my.action</field>
        <!-- and so on -->
        <field name="context">{'full_name': 1}</field>
    </record>
```

2. Variant non context-based -> it's the same as variant 1 without using the context at all. It will be system-wide at not only where you want it to be. It's the easier variant.